To detect Vision Pro in web browser
Vr.prototype.isMobileDevice = function() {
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || window.opera;

// Updated regular expressions for broader device detection, including hypothetical 'visionpro'
return /android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos/i.test(userAgent)
    || /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(userAgent);
    // Custom check for Vision Pro
    // Additional checks can be added here based on further unique characteristics
}

I am testing whether the browser is ready for XR, by detecting as above. In Vision Pro, it doesn't work so I wonder is there any way I can detect the device is Vision Pro?
I have added /visionpro/i.test(userAgent), and it didn't work.

I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable to add SOLVED to the title, or to eddit a solution into the question itself. If you've found a solution to the problem and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See Can I answer my own question? for more information. If you no longer want your question here, use the delete link below the tags to remove it.

That's great, and I see you've done so properly now instead of defacing your question. Thanks!

Checking userAgent string is currently not the way to detect a Vision Pro device, since I confirmed the userAgent string in Vision Pro doesn't contain "Vision" "Pro" or any combinations of these words.
After extensive search and failed trying (including what suggested by ChatGPT and Copilot), I came up with the following javascript code.
I don't recommend to use it, since it is obviously very poor way to detect Vision Pro, but nevertheless it works. Or at least for now it works. Here we go.
Vr.prototype.isMobileDevice = function() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || window.opera;
    // Regular expressions for mobile device detection
    return /android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos/i.test(userAgent)|| /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(userAgent);
}


Vr.prototype.isVisionPro = function() {
    if (this.isMobileDevice()) return false;
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    if (/Chrome|Windows|Oculus|Quest/i.test(userAgent)) return false;
    if (! this.app.xr.supported) return false;
    return true;
};


You can use this function to detect Vision Pro with only one single edge case being iPhone or iPad in desktop mode.
const isVisionProUser = () => {
   const isMacintosh = navigator.userAgent.includes('Macintosh');
   const hasFiveTouchPoints = navigator.maxTouchPoints === 5;
   return isMacintosh && hasFiveTouchPoints;
};

